# Trouble with scroll pane with nested layouts

Tags: java

I am having trouble adding a scroll pane to a nested panel. Here is what I have:

```
public class board {
    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        pane.add(left);
        left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel leftTop = new JPanel();
        leftTop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(266, 300));
        leftTop.setBackground(Color.black);
        left.add(leftTop);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(leftTop); //problem is here
        left.add(scrollPane); 

        JButton jb = new JButton();
        jb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
        leftTop.add(jb);

        JButton jb1 = new JButton();
        jb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
        leftTop.add(jb1);

        JButton jb2 = new JButton();
        jb2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
        leftTop.add(jb2);

        JButton jb3 = new JButton();
        jb3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
        leftTop.add(jb3);

        JButton jb4 = new JButton();
        jb4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
        leftTop.add(jb4);

        JButton jb5 = new JButton();
        jb5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
        leftTop.add(jb5);

        JButton jb6 = new JButton();
        jb6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
        leftTop.add(jb6);

        JPanel leftBottom = new JPanel();
        leftBottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(266, 300));
        leftBottom.setBackground(Color.red);
        left.add(leftBottom);

        JPanel middle = new JPanel();
        pane.add(middle);
        middle.setLayout(new BoxLayout(middle, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel middleTop = new JPanel();
        middleTop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(266, 200));
        middleTop.setBackground(Color.green);
        middle.add(middleTop);

        JPanel middleBottom = new JPanel();
        middleBottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(266, 400));
        middleBottom.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        middle.add(middleBottom);

        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(266, 600));
        right.setBackground(Color.blue);

        pane.add(right);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am just messing around with JPanels and I cannot seem to add scrolling to the left top pane. I think i initialized scrollPane right, but am I adding it to the wrong pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial problem is here

```
leftTop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(266, 300));
```

This is overriding what the layout manager (`FlowLayout` in this case) would otherwise provide to the `JScrollPane` in order for it to know how to manage the view (when to show the scrollbars for instance)

The next problem you will have is, `FlowLayout` won't do what you want it to.  Instead you might want to use `GridLayout` or maybe `GridBagLayout` instead

[image: ExampleLayout]

```
JPanel leftTop = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//leftTop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(266, 300));
leftTop.setBackground(Color.black);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(leftTop); //problem is here
left.add(scrollPane);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);
JButton jb = new JButton();
jb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
leftTop.add(jb, gbc);

JButton jb1 = new JButton();
jb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
leftTop.add(jb1, gbc);

JButton jb2 = new JButton();
jb2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
leftTop.add(jb2, gbc);

JButton jb3 = new JButton();
jb3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
leftTop.add(jb3, gbc);

JButton jb4 = new JButton();
jb4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
leftTop.add(jb4, gbc);

JButton jb5 = new JButton();
jb5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
leftTop.add(jb5, gbc);

JButton jb6 = new JButton();
jb6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 50));
leftTop.add(jb6, gbc);
```

Know, if that's not meeting your needs, you will need to create a custom component which implements [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html), which will allow you to specify `PreferredScrollableViewportSize` which will tell the `JScrollPane` what the preferred size of the viewable area should be, rather then using the `preferredSize` of the view

Comment: Ya I need it to be scrollable, should I keep the gridbaglayout still and create a custom component, or switch back to the gridlayout with a nested  boxlayout and add the custom component.

Comment: The example I've done is still "scrollable", you just need to resize the window so it's smaller then the preferred size.  The problem is, the `JScrollPane` will always want to be the preferred size of the container, hence the reason I mentioned `Scrollable`